# Loop Over Directories, Process files & Rename New Files

Tags: linux, bash, google-closure-compiler

I'm writing a script that would loop over the sub-directories of a given directory, find for ".js" files, compiles with closure. I'm doing this with this commands:

```
find ./js/ -type f -name "*.js" -exec java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js '{}' --js_output_file '{}'.compiled \;
```

And then removing the old ".js" files with:

```
find ./js/ -type f -name "*.js" | xargs rm -f
```

But, I can't rename the files with the names "foo.js.compiled" to "foo.js".

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.js.compiled"`; do mv $i ${i%.*} ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
find . -name "*.js.compiled" -exec rename -v 's/\.compiled$//' {} +
```

#### Test:

```
$ find . -name "foo*"
./fil/foo.js.compiled
$ find . -name "*.js.compiled" -exec rename -v 's/\.compiled$//' {} +
'./fil/foo.js.compiled' renamed to './fil/foo.js'
$ find . -name "foo*"
./fil/foo.js
```

Comment: it's not working. I've to iterate through all the files in a directory and its sub-directories.

Comment: It gives nothing. I've to iterate on the files with extension "*.js.compiler" and rename the file with "*.js". Yes I've rename availbale.

Comment: I was ruuning: `find ./js/ -name "*.js.compiled" -exec rename -v 's/\.compiled$//' {} +`

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
find ./js/ -name "*.js.compiled" -print0 | while read -r -d '' filename; do
  mv "$filename" "${filename/js.compiled/js}";
done
```